# What constraints produce a locus describing a circle where $AB$ is a chord of measure $\gamma$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, locus

Let points $A,B$ be fixed, and let $C$ vary, with the constraint that $\gamma := \angle ACB$ is fixed.  It is [well](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LocusOfPointsWithConstantAngle/) [known](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa08/Wisdom/Assignment%206/Locus%20of%20vertex%20C.html) that [the locus of $C$ is a double arc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342547/curve-for-constant-angle-for-two-fixed-points), where $AB$ is a chord of measure $2 * \angle ACB$.

What constraints describe a circle where $AB$ is a chord of measure $\gamma$?

I conjecture that if instead of requiring that $\gamma := \angle ACB$ we require that the [oriented angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4112869/oriented-angles-in-euclidean-geometry) $\measuredangle ABC$ is fixed to equal $\gamma$ this will describe such a circle.  However:

1. How do we prove this?
2. What about the points $A$ and $B$ themselves? They seem to be limiting cases that are approached for all $\gamma$ as $C$ approaches $A$ or $B$
3. Experimenting with this seems to show that in some extreme cases, we get not a circle but a line (which can be thought of as a generalized circle) or a point (a degenerate circle), but I'm having trouble characterizing this

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are fixed then $AB$ is a chord of a circle whose centre is any point on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$